# NodeJS request.post method issue

Tags: node.js, post, request

> Resolved: It seems that Mumbai university uses different servers for
>   different results, which i did notice.

I am writing a script to retrieve my results directly from my university website. But I am facing problems with the "request.post" method in "request" module of NodeJS.

Here's my code

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');
request.post({
    headers: {'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'content-length':69},
    url:     'http://results.mu.ac.in/get_resultc.php',
    body:    "exam_id=4050&exam_year=2016&exam_month=MAY&seat_no=45280208&submit=Go"
    }, function(error, response, body){
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        console.log($('html').text());
        var result = $('b').text();
        console.log(result);
});
```

I get the following output

```
.. 
..
No Such Seat No!!
```

But if i send the same post data with Burp I get the correct output as shown in the image below.

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClG7v.png)

Please let me know where I have gone wrong and what can be done. Thank You.

> NOTE: The shown query is a test query and is not related to my exam id
>   or seat number.

Comment: Well, posting the data in your example to that url returns 'No Such Seat No!!'.  I tried with Firefox and HttpRequester add-on, and it returned the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL in your code above point to:

```
url:     'http://results.mu.ac.in/get_resultc.php',
```

But the image points to:

```
url:     'http://results.mu.ac.in/get_resultb.php',
```

*"get_result**b**.php"*

Posting to get_resultb.php yeilds:

```
Results for B.E.Degree (COMPUTER ENGG.) (SEM-VIII) (CBSGS) held on MAY 2016

The result of seat number 45280208 is PassedCongratulations.
```

Comment: I didn't notice that. I had prepared my script on a previous result url. Thanks for bringing it up.